# How to create content fields and use in new page layout.?

Tags: 2013, page-layout, layouts

I have created a custom page layout. I want to use content fields in my custom layout. For example, an image field or page content field.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the mentioned steps below to create `a custom page layout` with the required field controls like `content field` and `image field`.

- First of all Specify, the field controls that you need to show within your custom page layout. like content field and image field.
- Create a site content type.

  - Go to Site Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Site Content Types.

[image]

- Click Create.

[image]

- Under `Parent Content Type` select `Publishing Content Types` then `Page`.
- Now Click on `Add from new site column` to create `content fields` and `image fields.`
- Set the name of your columns and Select `Full HTML` to `content field` and `Image with formatting` for `Image`.
- Now go to create a Page layout.

  - Site Settings > Design Manager > Click on Create a Page Layout > set the name of your page layout > select your master page > select your content type that you have just created.
- After the page layout created > Select your custom page layout > and From the above ribbon > select Publish.
- Now go back to your page that you need to use the custom page layout within it > edit it > select your custom page layout > you should now find the `content fields` and `image fields` and other fields that have been created within your `custom page layout`.